# Bootstrap 4 tabs - Only one isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an admin section for a site where admins can go in and change things about the site. I've split this page up into different sections using tabs and they've been working up until I added the most recent one and as soon as I did, one of the ones that was already there, stopped working.
Here's the code - The one that isn't working is the "Historical Fact of The Day" tab:

```
<!-- This is within a .container-fluid -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#potd" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link active">Photo of the Day</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#users" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Users</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#forum" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#hfotd" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Historical Fact of The Day</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#cntdwn" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Countdown</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="potd">
        <h3>Add a Photo of The Day</h3>
        <?php include 'create_potd.php'; ?>
        <h3>View Upcoming Photos of the Day</h3>
        <?php include 'view_potd.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="forum">
        <h3>Create a category</h3>
        <?php include 'create_cat.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="users">
        <h3>User List</h3>
        <?php include 'user_list.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="hfotd">
        <h3>Add a Historical Fact of The Day</h3>
        <?php include 'create_hfotd.php'; ?>
        <h3>View Upcoming Historical Facts of the Day</h3>
        <?php include 'view_hfotd.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cntdwn">
        <h3>Change the current countdown</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I really have no idea what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could very easily confirm this yourself by removing that include, try that first.

Comment: @DavidG Good idea! After doing so, I've found that it's not the include's problem

Comment: And you removed **all** includes? The code you posted is fine without them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. If your tabs are not working, then it must be to do with your included content. Check the browser console for errors, then check that the includes are producing valid HTML with all tags correctly opened and closed. Here is your code proven to work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- This is within a .container-fluid -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#potd" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link active">Photo of the Day</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#users" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Users</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#forum" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#hfotd" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Historical Fact of The Day</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#cntdwn" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Countdown</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="potd">
        <h3>Add a Photo of The Day</h3>
        php include 'create_potd.php';
        <h3>View Upcoming Photos of the Day</h3>
        php include 'view_potd.php';
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="forum">
        <h3>Create a category</h3>
        php include 'create_cat.php';
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="users">
        <h3>User List</h3>
        php include 'user_list.php';
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="hfotd">
        <h3>Add a Historical Fact of The Day</h3>
        php include 'create_hfotd.php';
        <h3>View Upcoming Historical Facts of the Day</h3>
        php include 'view_hfotd.php';
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cntdwn">
        <h3>Change the current countdown</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everybody! Realised I was using the #hfotd in a JavaScript function in my footer...
What a numpty.